# java overridden method does not throw java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

Tags: java

I am trying to clone an arraylist of objects.

In my interface, I have

```
public interface IBillingConditionDTO extends Cloneable {
    public Object clone();
}
```

In my class, I have

```
public class BillingConditionDTO implements IBillingConditionDTO {

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        BillingConditionDTO clone = null;
        try {
            clone = (BillingConditionDTO) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
        }
        return clone;
    }
}
```

But when I compile it, it says:

> BillingConditionDTO cannot implement clone() in IBillingConditionDTO; overridden method does not throw java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

What's wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

in the interface. Thanks for reading.